# Should I create a separate site in IIS to redirect (wildcard) from one domain to another?

Tags: redirects, dns, https, iis

We are moving domains and servers.   I have `newdomain.example` set up on new server (SSL).

I want to shut off old domain.   I will get old domain pointed to new server.

Is it better in IIS to add the `olddomain.example` bindings on new server under the same IIS Site?   Or is it better to create a new IIS site for `olddomain.example` and redirect it to the `newdomain.example` from there?

Another dimension in here is we could have links in both http and https but sites both require https.   So one of the things I am worried about is redirecting `http://olddomain.example/xyz/index.html` and that it needs to redirect correctly to `https://newdomain.example/xyz/index.html`

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've configured IIS, but if I recall correctly, the bindings will only identify that the new site is "listening" for the olddomain.com and forward to the active site, without telling your web client anything.

On the other hand, if you create a "new site" for the old domain, and use a redirect, then you will also communicate to the web client/browser that the site has been redirected (301 or 302) which will be better for your clients and for SEO in the long run. See IIS doc [HTTPRedirect IIS config](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/)